# textbox which accepts only alphabets using jquery mask

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

i am having the textbox which needs to accepts only alphabets i tried with jquery mask but its only for numeric i can able to do , but needs to enter only alphabets in a textbox can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), works very well.

```
<input type="text" id="textOnly" />

jQuery(function($){
   $("#textOnly").mask("aaaaaa");
});
```

This would accept 6 letters only.